# Setting variables to the same value as other variables in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to set the value of an old variable to a new one, like shown down here:

```
set %NEWLPATH%=%OLDLPATH%
```

So the variable `%NEWLPATH%` needs to get the same value as `%OLDLPATH%`. The code shown above does not seem to work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `%` on the left hand side of an assignment

```
set NEWLPATH=%OLDLPATH%
```

The `%` is only needed when *retrieving* the value of a variable.

Comment: all horses deserve names

Comment: @Monacraft don't cry `:-)`